# Subtraction between columns and several rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to expose my problem. I have a dataset of this type as you can see below. I would like to add a column to the dataset called `balance_required_for_next_bet`, is a variable calculated as follows:

(value of the `'balance'` variable of the row) - (value of the `'bet'` variable of the next line)

```
          Date      bet     current loss      current win    balance  
0   2016-08-20        8                8             0.00      -8.00       
1   2016-08-21       32               28            18.00     -18.00
2   2016-08-27       14               14             0.00     -32.00
```

here is an example of the new column to be added to the dataset with the calculation:

```
     balance required for next bet  (balance - next bet)
0           -8 - 32 ===> -40       
1          -18 - 14 ===> -32
2           -32 - 0 ===> -32
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how are you computing the last entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) operation on one of the rows. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'bet': [8, 32, 14], 'balance': [-8, -18, -32]})
df['next_bet'] = df.balance - df.bet.shift(-1).fillna(0)
#    bet  balance  next_bet
# 0    8       -8     -40.0
# 1   32      -18     -32.0
# 2   14      -32     -32.0
```

Shifting the `df.bet` column by `-1` effectively moves each entry *up* a row. By subtracting this shifted column from your `df.balance` column, you are subtracting the *next* bet from the *current* balance for each row. I add the `fillna(0)` to make sure you do not get any `NaN` values.